# Complete steps to write a hello world on testnets?

Tags: solidity, testnets

I am trying to learn about dapp development, but I'm stuck in what should be the easiest step. I've looked at least 6 different "getting started" tutorials; half of them are deprecated, the other half skip entirely the setup part and go straight to the language.

What is a complete step-by-step instruction for running a "hello world" contract in a test net starting from having geth installed on an Unix environment (and already knowing how to use it on the terminal to write transactions, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably one of the best tutorials:

https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/a-101-noob-intro-to-programming-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-695d15c1dab4#.tt2ajhnr3

I'd recommend starting with truffle and testrpc (as mentioned in the article).  Much easier to start out with than using the testnet.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This [collection of four articles](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) by Mahesh Murthy is excellent.  They use Web3 0.20.1, so it's probably best to have the [1.0 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) open at the same time.  The main gotcha is that `web3.eth.contract` has since become `web3.eth.Contract`.